# Scoping issue in backbone view

Tags: backbone.js, easeljs

I am in the process of getting a simple drawing view created using Easeljs inside of a Backbonejs view. I am having an issue with scope, in my listener events, for example:

```
this.stage.addEventListener("stagemousedown", this.handleMouseDown);
```

I started to started doing this to get around my scope issue

```
var self = this;
this.stage.addEventListener("stagemousedown", function(){
    var foo = self.bar;
});
```

However, this seems sloppy, especially since the sample code I am porting (http://www.createjs.com/#!/EaselJS/demos/drawing), has nested levels of eventListeners.

```
SketchView = Backbone.View.extend({


initialize: function(){
   this.canvas;
   this.stage;
   this.drawingCanvas;
   this.oldPt;
   this.oldMidPt;
   this.title;
   this.color;
   this.stroke;
   this.colors;
   this.index;
},

beforeRender : function (){
    this.template = _.template( tpl.get(this.templateFile) );
},

render: function(eventName) {
   $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model));
   return this;
},

//add in UI
afterRender : function (){
    this.createUI();
},

createUI: function() {
    this.canvas = document.getElementById("demoCanvas");
    this.index = 0;
    this.colors = ["#828b20", "#b0ac31", "#cbc53d", "#fad779", "#f9e4ad", "#faf2db", "#563512", "#9b4a0b", "#d36600", "#fe8a00", "#f9a71f"];

    //Create a stage by getting a reference to the canvas
    this.stage = new createjs.Stage(this.canvas);
    this.stage.autoClear = false;
    this.stage.enableDOMEvents(true);

    createjs.Touch.enable(this.stage);
    createjs.Ticker.setFPS(24);

    this.stage.addEventListener("stagemousedown", this.handleMouseDown);
    this.stage.addEventListener("stagemouseup", this.handleMouseUp);

    this.title = new createjs.Text("Click and Drag to draw", "36px Arial", "#777777");
    this.title.x = 300;
    this.title.y = 200;
    this.stage.addChild(this.title);

    this.stage.addChild(this.drawingCanvas);
    this.stage.update();
 },

handleMouseDown: function (event) {
        if (this.stage.contains(this.title)) { this.stage.clear(); this.stage.removeChild(this.title); }
        this.color = this.colors[(this.index++)%this.colors.length];
        this.stroke = Math.random()*30 + 10 | 0;
        this.oldPt = new createjs.Point(this.stage.mouseX, this.stage.mouseY);
        this.oldMidPt = this.oldPt;
        this.stage.addEventListener("stagemousemove" , this.handleMouseMove);
    },

   handleMouseMove: function (event) {
        var midPt = new createjs.Point(this.oldPt.x + this.stage.mouseX>>1, this.oldPt.y+this.stage.mouseY>>1);

        this.drawingCanvas.graphics.clear().setStrokeStyle(this.stroke, 'round', 'round').beginStroke(this.color).moveTo(midPt.x, midPt.y).curveTo(this.oldPt.x, this.oldPt.y, this.oldMidPt.x, this.oldMidPt.y);

        this.oldPt.x = this.stage.mouseX;
        this.oldPt.y = this.stage.mouseY;

        this.oldMidPt.x = midPt.x;
        this.oldMidPt.y = midPt.y;

        this.stage.update();
    },

    handleMouseUp: function (event) {
        this.stage.removeEventListener("stagemousemove" , this.handleMouseMove);
    }

});
```

An unrelated question, is should I be instantiating my variables in the initialize function?  I am still new to Backbone, and trying to figure out best practices.

Comment: I usually just do this pattern: `this.stage.addEventListener("stagemousedown", _.bind(this.handleMouseDown,this));` which uses underscore's bind: http://underscorejs.org/#bind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backbone requires the Underscore library, and I strongly recommend becoming familiar with it : it has a lot of great stuff.  In particular it has a `_.bind` method that you can use like so:

```
this.stage.addEventListener("stagemousedown", _(function(){
    var foo = this.bar; // "this" will be correct now thanks to bind
}).bind(this);
```

It also has a related `_.bindAll` method, which can be used (often inside of an `initialize` function) to bind an object's methods to it, like so:

```
initialize: function() {
    _(this).bindAll('handleMouseDown'); // handleMouseDown's this will be correct
    this.stage.addEventListener("stagemousedown", this.handleMouseDown);
}
```

However, you can avoid all of this and let Backbone do the binding for you if you just take advantage of its event handling:

```
Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {mousedown: 'handleMouseDown'}
    handleMouseDown: function() {
        // this will be bound correctly
```

As for your question about instantiating variables inside `initialize`, the answer is  ... probably, but it's hard to say without knowing your specific context.  In general, `initialize` should do anything that needs to happen when the Collection/Model/View gets created, so if initializing variables falls under that then sure.

Comment: The only gotcha with this is that it will replace the context of the listener with that of the view.